# Can't manually create user using devise because of 'admin' field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, admin

Using Devise, I created the user model, and later I added an **:admin** field with `default => false` to my model using a migration.
Now I need to manually create an admin user ,so in the rails console I tried : 
`superadmin = User.create({ :email => 'email@mail.com', :password => '12345678' , :admin=> true })`
but getting the error below :

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in`debug_protected_attribute_removal'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in`sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in`initialize'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:46:in `initialize'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in`new'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
>       from (irb):4
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in`start'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in`'
>       from script/rails:6:in `require'
>       from script/rails:6:in`'

so is there another way of creating users manually?(using command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to `admin`, but it's currently not accessible to assignment. To fix this, you need to declare the `admin` attribute [`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :admin
end
```

This will enable you to create a new user in the precise fashion you've depicted.

Comment: another error : `SyntaxError: (irb):30: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'` looks like it only accepts :email and :password

Comment: What are you trying to enter into the Rails console? Also, are you sure you're in the Rails console? Your error is indicating that you're in `irb`.

Comment: What about creating a non-admin user and then changing the attribute if possible? Is there any method to change a specific method?

Comment: That's really not a workaround that you should need to be doing. The fix should be easy. How are you trying to create a new user in console? Try `User.create(:email => 'email@mail.com', :password => '12345678', :admin=> true)`

Comment: I'm sure.simply : `rails c`

Comment: `superadmin = User.create({ :email => 'e@iust.ir', :password => '12345678' :admin = true })` thats the code

Comment: Try the following (it should return an error): `User.create!(:email => 'email@mail.com', :password => '12345678', :admin=> true)`. What is the error it returns?

Comment: the code you suggested above successfully created the user but i cannot sign the user in ,in my browser.I must point that i added :confirmable to my model so any user must activate his acount through his e-mail

Comment: I see. So it seems that my answer resolved your issue. Would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?